# Plot only TRUE values from a logical vector in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a vector of logical values:

```
whatever <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

When I plot that vector, R draws a symbol at `y = 1` for all the `TRUE` values and at `y = 0` for all the `FALSE` values:

```
plot(whatever)
```

[image]

What I want is a symbol for only the `TRUE` values at `y = 4`:

[image]

*I'm looking for a solution in base R.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this :

```
plot(ifelse(whatever, 4, NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Plot at `4` with an y-axis up to `10`.

```
plot(rep(4, length(whatever))[whatever], ylim = c(0, 10))
```